# maatwebsite 3.1 stores formula text not calculated value

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am importing microsoft excel files to a database using `maatwebsite 3.1`. All cell with no formula were imported perfectly. but those cells with formula store the text of the formula not the calculated value. 
I tried "`use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;`". I also tried to store the value on disk before importing it.

I keep on getting something like `=IF(ISNUMBER(GEOMEAN(G5:AD5)),G5/H5," - ")` in the database where I should get `123.4567`

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. 
1.I have to write my Imports/App/XyzImports using WithCalculatedFormulas
it worked perfectly.

Comment: The solution actually is: to include the WithCalculatedFormulas